# Same position and animation of dynamic generated Images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

I have a few elements positioned in my HTML. The body has a max-width from 1280px with margin auto. And there are a few elements, which I floated right. In the middle of the page there should be 70 images go from left to right (and then dissapear). I have tried to make those elements position absolute with display: inline, but since the start and the end position should always be the same, and the images have a width and a height, I didn't know how to make it dynamically.. Thats my code so far:

HTML

```
<body>
    <h1>Sweets</h1>
    <div class="images"></div>
    <div id="display"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="maracons"></div>
    <div id="cupCake"></div>
</body>
```

JQUERY

```
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $('.images').append('<img class="image' + i.toString() + '" src="img/' + arr[i][5] + '">');
  }
```

CSS

```
$leftPos: 1100px;
$widthImage: 200px;

.images{
    width: $widthProducts;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 1100px;
    top: 0px;
}

.image-1{
    left: $leftPos;
}

.image-2{
    left: $leftPos - $widthImage;
}

.image-3{
    left: $leftPos - $widthImage*2;
}
```

Here is how it looks like:

[image: Position of my Elements]

Comment: you should provide relevant HTML markup in question and maybe a jsfiddle so maybe someone could help you.

Comment: I have added my HTML, but I am not sure if this is now more helpful than before..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confusing question but from what I gather you want the images to have dynamic height/width when you are appending them? If so what do you want to make the width/height equal?

If thats the case here is the answer:

```
 var imgWidth = 10, imgHeight = 10;
 for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    imgWidth = 100; //Set width
    imgHeight = 100; //Set height
    $('.images').append('<img style="width:' + imgWidth +'px!important; height:' + imgHeight + 'px !important; " class="image' + i.toString() + '" src="img/' + arr[i][5] +'">');
   }
```

the !important keyword will force the width/height specified to ignore the width/height specified in the class..

sorry if this is not what you mean, a jsfiddle would be great.

**UPDATE**

Check this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/xP8Qb/

Here is the kinda thing you were looking for:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var endpoint = 800; //you can set left+top endpoints and ref them in loop below..
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var html = '<div class="imgs img'+i+'"></div>';
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.images').append(html);
        $('.images>.imgs:last').animate({"left" : "300px"}, endpoint);
    }, i * 1000);
}
});
```

i can work on it more if needed, but hopefully this is enough to put you on the right track..

Comment: thanks for your answer, but that is not what I was looking for... I want to position the images at the same x and y coordinate and animate it to the same end point..

Comment: OK sorry - sounds like fun, let me work on it for a few mins.